# precompile error while deploying using capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I am getting the following error while deploying using capistrano 3

```
 INFO [5d0ddb5f] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile on 162.243.253.220
DEBUG [5d0ddb5f] Command: cd /home/deployer/apps/nabthat/releases/20131227083740 && (     RAILS_ENV=staging ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [5d0ddb5f]    /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby /home/deployer/apps/nabthat/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake assets:precompile:all   RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets
DEBUG [5d0ddb5f]    
DEBUG [5d0ddb5f]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [5d0ddb5f]    
DEBUG [5d0ddb5f]    database configuration does not specify adapter
DEBUG [5d0ddb5f]    
DEBUG [5d0ddb5f]       /home/deployer/apps/nabthat/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-  3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in   `resolve_hash_connection
```

I deploy using the command

```
bundle exec staging deploy
```

but error shows RAILS_ENV=staging, how to change it to production

i tried

```
bundle exec staging deploy RAILS_ENV="production"
```

still same error

Comment: changin my database.yml with staging setup clears my error, i don know why

Comment: i want to use the production setup from database.yml to be used for staging also